# VS2012 Project Reference's Properties' path does not match .vbproj HintPath

Tags: visual-studio-2012

My goal was to update a reference from my old DLL to a newer version that was updated to VS2012.

```
D:\DEV\<old_path>\TEST\bin\Company.dll
D:\DEV\<new_path_2012>\TEST\bin\Company.dll
```

In the .vbproj file...

```
<Reference Include="Company, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral">
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
  <HintPath>..\..\<new_path_2012>\TEST\bin\Company.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

In the Solution Explorer, Under References, I right-click on the Company reference and click Properties.  The Path is listed as...

```
D:\DEV\<old_path>\TEST\bin\Company.dll
```

There are no errors or warnings.  Everything is appearing to build properly however I lack confidence because of this discrepancy.  How can I fix this?

I have tried restarting VS2012 and have tried deleting the TFS Cache.  Downloading a fresh copy of this project from TFS on another PC seems to resolve the problem however I would like to better understand how to resolve this without such drastic measures.

Comment: How did you upgrade the reference? What did you do in VS? The path in properties windows should be derived from `HintPath`. You probably already tried reloading the project / solution?

Comment: Within Solution Explorer, to remove the reference: I click view all files -> References folder -> Right-click the reference to remove -> Delete.  Then, to add the reference: Right-click Reference folder -> Add Reference -> Browse to the new file -> Click OK

Comment: and yes, I have closed the solution and re-opened it from the Source Control Explorer.  I have also tried "Get Latest Version" while its closed, but it just reports all files are up-to-date.  The problem remains when I open the solution again.

Comment: You could try cleaning the solution or manually deleting the `bin` and `obj` folders. This should at least make the build fail if it doesn't search for the dll in the right place.

Answer (score 1):

I just had this issue crop up, and while this is an old thread it was the first Google result when I did my search, so I thought to offer what had happen for me.

TL;DR: Triple check the hint path - it could be wrong, and VS is using the DLL in the GAC.

My issue came up because I was using a little script to help me update over 250 projects worth of references, and had a small handful that didn't follow normal folder layout.  So my hint path was 'correct' at first glance, but because it really wasn't, VS 2013 went to the version of the DLL in the GAC.

Once I clued into what was wrong and fixed the relative path for that project file, hint path and what was displayed in References matched up as it was supposed to.